# ActiveX component can't create object with reg-free com until after restart

Tags: com, vb6, activex, regfreecom

When I install a new version of the application that is using an ActiveX library through Reg-free com (using a manifest file) I get "ActiveX component can't create object" error. However, when I restart the machine and run the application again, the error is gone. No other applications are using the com dll.

Any idea what is causing this?  Is there another way to successfully distribute this application without having to restart the machine?

Comment: Those symptoms make no sense, but we don't have enough information.  Check to see what has ended up in the VirtualStore parts of both the filesystem and the registry following reboot.  I suspect you are making quite a mess on "victim" systems.

Comment: When I've written isolated COM solutions, all that is necessary is to do an xcopy of my directory tree to some directory on the target machine and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This be a case where the EXE timestamp needs to be updated so that Windows recognizes the manifest. The manifest might be copied in after the EXE by the installer.

Perhaps on reboot, the 'cache' of the manifest gets invalidated which is why it then works correctly thence.

See additional: [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/10/25/touch-the-exe-after-you-added-a-manifest-for-it-in-vista/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741726/diagnosing-windows-application-manifests).