# VB6 Preventing Display Scalilng (DPI Aware) Not Working

Tags: windows, vb6, display, dpi

i have a package/app/tool developed in vb6 that I need to run/open without scaling  in case running windows has enabled dpi scaling like 125% or 150%.

so, after some google search i have found that i need to embed a manifest in my exe file and set `dpiAware` to true? so, i tried that but still same :(

here is the screenshot how it looks like if the display is with 125% scaling:

[image]

here the black/blue border area is the actual app/window area. and the red area is used/scaled by windows when display is 125%. (i set app form back color to red).

and here is the manifest part where i used `dpiAware`:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
  <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
  <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
</windowsSettings>
</application>
```

i even tried to set `dpiAware` to `false`, but same outcome..

so, it looks like manifest is not the solution here? or i missing something/part?

thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: Note - the manifest does not have to be embedded, it can also just be a separate file named appropriately.  But be aware of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589994/3195477.  This may make it easier to edit/test the manifest.

Comment: There is also `<dpiAwareness>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

Comment: Run Task Manager, details tab. Make sure the "DPI Awareness" column is shown. Then you can easily see how Windows has loaded your program.

Comment: @StayOnTarget, thanks a lot for your times in commenting and editing my post. sir, <dpiAwareness> is for windows 10 and later, i first trying to solve the issue on windows 7 etc.

Comment: @SalmaBegum It's been a few years since I worked in vb6 now, but what is the form's scalemode property set to?  I wonder if a container inside is set to pixels and the form is twips (which you may not be able to change that)

Comment: @JimmySmith, sir, my form scale mode is Twips, and form has a picture box which scale mode is set to pixel. can you guide me what needs to be changed? and also do you have source code or the executable of your old vb6 app that works fine with my issue/case? please?

Comment: @JimmySmith, i tried to change from scale mode from "twips" to "pixel" but that didn't work :(

Comment: What did Task Manager reveal about the running application EXE?

Comment: @StayOnTarget, on windows7 there is no such column in task manger, and on windows 10, it says system.

Comment: @SalmaBegum sorry for late reply.  what happens when you use twips for the picturebox scalemode?  Twips was the way they intended to prevent these troubles

Comment: @JimmySmith, sir, i have tried all possible combiation of twips and pixel on form and picturebox, like follow, PP, PT, TP, TT, but none of them works :(