# sxs manifest doesn't take effect after first time

Tags: com, winsxs, sxs

My application (myapp.exe) needs to use 2 COM objects that can't be loaded at the same time - they have conflicting dependencies in their manifests. So, my plan:

1. Keep 2 additional copies of the manifest:

   - myapp.exe.manifest.comp1 - references comp1.manifest
   - myapp.exe.manifest.comp2 - references comp2.manifest
2. Before I run myapp.exe, copy the desired myapp.exe.manifest.comp1/2 to overwrite myapp.exe.manifest.

However, I found that Windows still uses the original myapp.exe.manifest, see Test below. It seems Windows keep some kind manifest cache somewhere?

**Question:** How can I replace manifests, and get the replaced manifests to take effect?

## Test

1. Copy myapp.exe.manifest.comp1 myapp.exe.manifest
2. Run myapp.exe

   - **Result:** myapp.exe.manifest.comp1 takes effect, and comp1 works
3. Close myapp.exe, and Copy /y myapp.exe.manifest.comp2 myapp.exe.manifest
4. Run myapp.exe

   - **Expected:** myapp.exe.manifest.comp2 takes effect, and comp2 works
   - **Actual result:** myapp.exe.manifest.comp1 still takes effect, and so comp2 doesn't work

### Investigation:

- Looking in [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), I see that when I run myapp.exe, some other processes (the launching powershell.exe, and also csrss.exe) do access myapp.exe.manifest. So it's not completely ignored...
- Using [sxstrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sxstrace), I see that myapp.exe.manifest is getting used. But I see afterwards that Windows only searches in the paths taken from myapp.exe.manifest.comp1

**Edit:** An alternative would be to:

- Load manifests in runtime using [Activation Context APIs - ActivateActCtx etc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-activateactctx), but so far I haven't gotten that to work...
- From comment: For unmanaged code, use [SetDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw)/[AddDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory)
- For managed code, use [app.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element)  and/or [AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads)

Comment: There shouldn't be any cache. Does myapp.exe (all possible instances) exit between 3 and 4?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, there is a manifest cache. Programs are not expected to change manifests. Manifests are for static dependencies, not dynamic ones. For dynamic dependencies, you'll have to do things like SetDllDirectory.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, I suspected as much. I will try to handle dynamic dependencies, and failing that, will try to decide on the manifest at install time. However, is there a (documented?) way to somehow reset the cache? Even just for development purposes?

Comment: The cache is easy enough to work around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589994/3195477

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diagnosing Windows application manifests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741726/diagnosing-windows-application-manifests)

Comment: @StayOnTarget Yes it does! Especially the comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759413/552510), which says there are 2 caches!

Comment: @Jonathan glad it helped!  I've been thru the same learning curve :)   Normally I just edit the manifest file, run the weird copy /b command, and its fine.